# How can I use parameters with distinct function?

Tags: sql-injection, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm translating from one query language to Orient SQL and would like to prevent SQL injection. I have all of the injection points protected except for when I create an Orient SQL statement that uses the distinct function. I thought I could just do something like this

```
SELECT distinct(?) as distinctTag FROM V
```

However that does not work. I also tried to use double quotes around the question mark but that didn't make a difference. All I get back is the question mark in my result set. Below is the code I'm using to execute the query in Orient

```
String queryString = buildTranslation();
OrientBaseGraph graph = (OrientBaseGraph)idGraph.getBaseGraph();
OSQLSynchQuery<OrientVertex> oQuery = new OSQLSynchQuery<>(visitor.getTranslation());
return graph.command(oQuery).execute(getParameters());
```

Comment: What data is the getParameters() function returning?

Comment: @dgiannotti- Its returning the String values for the ? in the query. Its an array of Strings since execute() expects Varargs.